# Spring cloud stream produce array of messages, consume one message at a time

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I am having a simple case that I need to implement using spring cloud stream 3.2.4 version.
I have a scheduled producer of messages:

```
public class MySourceOfMessagesImpl {

    private Random random = new Random();
    private StreamBridge streamBridge;

    public MySourceOfMessagesImpl(StreamBridge streamBridge) {
        this.streamBridge = streamBridge;
    }
    
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
    public void get() {
        String payload = "my payload: " + random.nextInt();
        String payload2 = "my payload 2: " + random.nextInt();
        List<Message<String>> message = List.of(MessageBuilder.createMessage(payload, new MessageHeaders(Map.of())), MessageBuilder.createMessage(payload2, new MessageHeaders(Map.of())));
        streamBridge.send("myOutDestination", message);
    }
}
```

and a consumer:

```
public class MyTransformingProcessor implements Consumer<Message<String>> {
    private final StreamBridge streamBridge;

    public MyTransformingProcessor(StreamBridge streamBridge) {
        this.streamBridge = streamBridge;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "myOutDestination")
    public void accept(Message<String> source) {
        //some transformations here
        streamBridge.send("mykafkatopic-out-0", source);
    }
}
```

The thing is, MyTransformingProcessor is getting an ArrayList<> instead of single message. Is there a way to instruct the framework to send a list of messages as separate items?

Answer (score 0):

The unit of work in messaging is indeed a `Message`, not list of messages.

So, if you have a list of them, you have to iterate and use `streamBridge.send()` for individual items.

Not clear why do you need that extra `Consumer` when you simply can use `streamBridge.send("mykafkatopic-out-0")` in your scheduled method.